# Is it necessary the scope resolution in this case?

Tags: c++, inheritance, static, member

Do we need to include the scope

```
baseClass::statmember.methodmember();
```

in a call to a static member of the base class that has been inherited when we call it from inside a method of the derived class?
I see it in a code programed by other person, I try to modify it and it compiles as well without including the scope

```
derivedclass::methodDerived() {
    statmember.methodmember();
};
```

Why the programmer has included in all the calls to the member the `scope::` if its unnecessary? Is it a reminder of the unicity of the static member in all the objects?

Or I am wrong and the code may give different results?

Comment: Can you post some **actual** code?  It's not clear what you're talking about.

Comment: Eh, thanks for the answer, but I can't indeed,it's forbiden I think. Privacity policy of the developers.I'll try to refine the question.

Comment: It may be necessary for templates.

Comment: The base class it's not a template.Thanks

Comment: No: but a derived class can be a template if the base isn't? Maybe overriding the constructor ?? It sounds me difficult to manage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be necessary only if the base class and the derived class have a function with the same name, and you want to distinguish between them.

Otherwise it's not necessary.

Comment: Oh, IT is what I believe. Thanks a bundle!

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing it's because the following is allowed:

```
class Base
{
public:
   static void foo(){}
};
class Derived:public Base
{
public:
   static void foo(){}
};
```

Either that, or for readability. Sometimes, just because it isn't necessary doesn't mean it has no use (even if that use is readability, which is a biggie).